# TempData from Global ASAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tempdata

Can someone post a sample code on how I can access the TempData dictionary object from within the Global.asax.cs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, object> tempDataDictionary = HttpContext.Current.Session["__ControllerTempData"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
```

Comment: Thanks, jfar. Your answer helped me get it right, but it is not 100% correct as there is some compile time errors with it. I used HttpContext.Current.Session instead of httpContext.Session, please edit your response so people can use it in the future.

Comment: You will also need to check that `tempDataDictionary` is not `null` if nothing else has been added to TempData up until this point. MVC3.